# Como puedo obtener la posicion de un item en un spinner sabiendo su contenido?

Tags: android-studio, android-spinner

tengo una actividad en la que guardo los valores de un spinner (solamente el contenido) en una base de datos MySQLite, pero además tengo una actividad en la cual modifico los valores de esa columna de la base de datos con otro spinner, pero para eso primero obtengo los datos de la base de datos, los modifico y se actualizan (eso deberia hacer) pero tengo la duda de como hacerlo, pensaba en algo como "spinner.setPosition where contenido = 20"
Cabe mencionar que son 2 spinners y cada uno obtiene los valores de una forma diferente, siendo una de el archivo strings.xml de un  y el otro de la forma que se muestra abajo

```
//ADAPTADOR DEL SPINNER DE SEXO
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapterSexo = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
            R.array.sexo_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapterSexo.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    //ADAPTADOR DEL SPINNER DE EDAD
    List<String> numeros = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int x = 14; x <= 25; x++) {
        numeros.add(String.valueOf(x));
    }
    //Se le asigna el adaptador al spinner de edad
    edad.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, numeros));
    //Se le asigna el adaptador al spinner de sexo
    sexo.setAdapter(adapterSexo);
```

Aqui es donde ocupo hacer los updates pero no se como :(
`

```
private void Buscar() {
        AdminSQLiteOpenHelper admin = new AdminSQLiteOpenHelper(this, "baseDatos", null, 1);
        SQLiteDatabase database = admin.getWritableDatabase();

        String name = nombre.getText().toString();

        if (!name.isEmpty()){
            Cursor row = database.rawQuery("SELECT nombre, domicilio, sexo, edad FROM usuarios WHERE nombre='"+name+"'", null);
            if (row.moveToFirst()){
                nombre.setText(row.getString(0));
                domicilio.setText(row.getString(1));
//Se que esta mal de esta manera pero espero haberme dado a entender
                String x = row.getString(2);
                sexo.setSelection(Integer.parseInt(x));
//--------------------------------SPINNERS-----------------------------------
                sexo.setText(row.getString(2));
                edad.setText(row.getString(3));
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
                database.close();
            } else{
                Toast.makeText(this, "No existe el usuario", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                database.close();
            }
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(this, "Favor de introducir un nombre", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            database.close();
        }
    }`
```

Answer (score 0):

No entendí bien tu pregunta y no puedo comentar , pero intentare ayudarte.

Primero necesitas traer el valor de la base de datos, traes el sexo(Hombre)
y luego haces un switch

```
switch(sexo){
  case "Hombre": posición = 1;
  break;
  default: posición=0(Esta es cuando no tiene sexo definido);
  break;
}
```

Nota: Ve como obtienes el string, si empieza con mayúscula o minúscula, ya que tiene que ser igual como te la regresa la consulta. Sexo es la variable donde guardas el valor de la base de datos(String). La posición del arreglo no se como la tengas pero recuerda que empieza de 0,1,2..

Una vez que ya tienes la posición puedes ponerla en el spinner.

```
spinner.setSelection(posición);
```

Espero haberte ayudado.